# How to retrieve filename from OpenCV's VideoCapture() in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

After we've created `VideoCapture` with `cv2.VideoCapture(filename)` how can we retrieve `filename`? Looks like `get()` method with `propId` is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but you cannot retrieve the filename from a cv2.VideoCapture.

(also, webcams or ip captures wont even have one)

since the filename is in your code, you need to cache it in a variable instead.